# wampserver configuration issues

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

My environment is **WampServer Version 2.5** running **Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12/ MySQL 5.6.17**.

The `localhost` works fine and I can see the `project folders` in the `DocumentRoot`. When I try to navigate the `project folders` via the links, the browser cannot find them. For example if I try to open `test` folder inside `www`, i.e. `localhost-->test` results in the `test folder` not found and apparently the url in the browser shows `http://test/`. But if I manually enter the location in the browser like `http://localhost/test/`, then I can see the project and then on wards can navigate the subfolders via links.

I want to be able to navigate the project from my `localhost` rather than typing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wamp 2.5 can use virtual host. [here is nice tutorial](http://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp). But if you still want to use localhost use this:

in WWW director -> index.php file search for:

```
$suppress_localhost = true; // line 30
```

and set this to false:

```
$suppress_localhost = false;
```

And to make work the "My Projects" from tray menu you need to edit the `refresh.php` file from `c:\Wamp\scripts` on line 651 replace:

```
$myreplacesubmenuProjects .= 'Type: item; Caption: "'.$projectContents[$i].'"; Action: run; FileName: "'.$c_navigator.'"; Parameters: "http://'.$projectContents[$i].'/"; Glyph: 5 ';
```

with:

```
$myreplacesubmenuProjects .= 'Type: item; Caption: "'.$projectContents[$i].'"; Action: run; FileName: "'.$c_navigator.'"; Parameters: "http://localhost/'.$projectContents[$i].'/"; Glyph: 5 ';
```

and right on tray icon and click "Refresh".

Comment: Yes that did the trick. Was it documented somewhere? Seems like I missed it.

Comment: i don't found this on the web but i open one ticket on the sourceforge. is the some bug if you try to select tray icon-> My Projects.

Comment: I just found out actually at http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123740,123752. It is not a bug but an intended feature for the good practices. The recommendation there is to create Virtual Hosts for all your projects even those that you store in the `\wamp\www\project1` style folders. This is the proper way of configuring the project so that it matches the environment that one might find in the hosting server. I have marked your answer as correct since it solves the issue raised on the first hand.

Comment: This is a VERY BAD Solution! As SASM says, you should create a Virtual Host for each of your projects.

Comment: if I already have several projects in www folder and want to work locally and are not configure the vhost so many projects? why not have this alternative to work locally without virtual host?